# Python multiprocessing slower than single

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, pypy

Sort.py

```
import random
import time

def time_analysis(func):
    def do_func(*args, **kwargs):
        print('[INFO] \'{}\' analysis started (N={}).'.format(func.__name__, len(args[0])))
        start_time = time.clock()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.clock()
        total_time = end_time - start_time
        print('[INFO] \'{}\' took {} seconds (N={}).'.format(func.__name__, total_time, len(args[0])))
        return result

    return do_func


@time_analysis
def bubble_sort(num_list):
    num_len = len(num_list)
    for i in range(num_len - 1):
        for j in range(num_len - i - 1):
            if num_list[j] > num_list[j + 1]:
                num_list[j], num_list[j + 1] = num_list[j + 1], num_list[j]
    return num_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 30000
    random_list = list(range(N))
    random.shuffle(random_list)
    bubble_sort(random_list)

    random_list = list(range(N))
    random.shuffle(random_list)
    bubble_sort(random_list)
```

Parallel.py

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from Sort import *

def bubble_sort_parallel(*args, **kwargs):
    return bubble_sort(*args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 30000
    random_list = list(range(N))
    random.shuffle(random_list)
    pool.apply_async(bubble_sort_parallel, (random_list,))
    random_list = list(range(N))
    random.shuffle(random_list)
    pool.apply_async(bubble_sort_parallel, (random_list,))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Single thread took only 2 seconds but Multiprocessing took 8 seconds.

N = 300,000. Single thread took only 200 seconds but Multiprocessing took 1400 seconds.

Why using multiprocessing is slower than single thread?

How could I improve the performance?

Platform: Linux, pypy2.7-5.10.0, 4 Cores on my computer

Multiprocessing:
[Figure of multiprocessing][https://i.stack.imgur.com/QksXf.png]

Single thread:
[Figure of single thread][https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HYw7.png]

Comment: When I run `Sort.py` on its own, I get `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`. Is that intended? How are you getting the timing of the single threaded approach?

Comment: Have you also considered the fact that the arrays you pass to the multiprocessing version vs the normal version are different? That may impact performance. Also, how many cores do you have on your machine?

Comment: I notice that `random.shuffle` returns None, so that may be impacting your runtime: you're not actually passing a list to your sorting functions.

Comment: I assume that you're using BubbleSort purely to have something to run while experimenting with multiprocessing. For actual sorting purposes, BubbleSort is only useful to demonstrate its inferiority to almost every other (sane) sorting algorithm. ;)

Comment: Sorry, i have put on the wrong code.
I have corrected it.

Comment: BubbleSort it's not porformance, but why multiprocessing is slower than sigle thread ?

Comment: If you increase the list size to 300,000 does the difference between parallel and sequential runtime remain consistent?

Comment: I have try 300,000.
Parallel took 1400 seconds and sequential tool only 200 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this much was already clear to you: `Pool.apply_async` allows you to dispatch work to other processes in the pool; it does not automatically parallelize a single function.  In other words, both versions are performing each sort in a single thread on a single core.  The parallel version ought to dispatch the two sort calls to two cores, but you're measuring the runtime of each sort, not the whole program's execution, so you would not detect any savings via the overlap of the two sort invocations.  (Additionally, at present, your code does not include the creation of the pool object, so I am just *assuming* that you used `processes=N` for *N* > 2--though, again, it wouldn't matter since you're not measuring the overall runtime but rather the runtime of each sort.)

(If not, see
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers
and
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)

This, however, does not explain why simply dispatching the work to another process results in a slower runtime.  (It is worth noting that on my MacBook Pro, there is no difference in execution time between the simple version and the "parallel" version.)  The reason for the slowness is the communication between the processes.  You're asking it to transfer a big list through its IPC channel and it is apparently not efficient at doing so.  You can demonstrate this for yourself: Move the list creation and shuffling into `bubble_sort_parallel` and make the argument to the supplied function in `pool.apply_async` the empty list.  On my computer, this makes the runtime identical to the basic version.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried with `N=15000`. On my computer it worked almost the same time, that is, non-parallel version sorted one array in 26 sec. and parallel version sorted two arrays in 28 sec. I set `pool = Pool(2)`. Have you tried to increase N, maybe your results will be comparable for larger values of N in your environment.

p.s. You should also keep in mind that spawning processes also requires resources and there are some synchronisation tools involved.